# How can I get a 'String...' wrapper?

Tags: java

I want to get **A**'s constructor by 'Class.getConstructor'.

#### A.class

```
public class A {
    public A(String... param) {
    }
}
```

#### Class.getConstructor

```
public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class... parameterTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    ...
}
```

How can i get a **String...** wrapper?

Comment: What do you mean, a wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String...` is a syntactic sugar for an array of strings.

As far as Reflection is concerned, it's just `String[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `class A` constructor is basically using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs).

> You can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of
>   values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a
>   particular type of argument will be passed to the method. It's a
>   shortcut to creating an array manually (the previous method could have
>   used varargs rather than an array).

basically that method is same as:

```
public class A {
    public A(String[] param) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer